# A question about wire area

Tags: wire

For some reason I need a flexible wire whose cross-section is equilateral triangle with the length of one side is 2mm.

I couldn't find any wire or even material in the market in such shape.

So Im planning to find the closest possible round wire option.

If I would use a triangular cross section's area would be:

sqrt(3)/4 * d^2 where d is the edge length

for d = 2mm

Are becomes 1.732mm^2

So I need to find a cable with around this area.

From the tables I could closest find 15AWG which corresponds 1.6502mm^2

Is my way of thinking correct?

In wire sizing AWG is measure for the entire wire together with its coat or for the copper part only?

Comment: why triangular?

Comment: AWG measures the size of the conductor (the copper part).

Comment: As soon as you bend a wire with a triangular cross section you create a sharp edge that will try and cut its way through the insulation. I'm not surprised you can't find any.

Comment: The suspense is killing me! What is the reason you need this? It feels *extremely unlikely you actually need that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your thinking is correct. The wire gauge refers to the copper only, because the insulation thickness can vary widely based on the application. Transformer wire will have very thin enamel insulation, while spark plug wire will have very thick silicone rubber insulation.